# Install Meteor on ubuntu ssl certificate error

Tags: installation, meteor

When I try to install meteor on ubuntu(11.04) :

```
**$ curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh**
```

I got the following message:

` % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                     Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
      0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
    error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
    More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

```
curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.`
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some kind of SSL CA certificate error, try

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

and try again

Also well the below should also work just fine:

```
curl http://install.meteor.com --insecure | /bin/sh
```

Comment: $ sudo update-ca-certificates 
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
done.
done.

Then I run curl http://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh or curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh , it showes the same error.

Comment: Can you try without the s in https. Also your system clock might not be right if the certificates are all ok. Another option is to add `--insecure` i've updated the answer to show this

Comment: I manage to solve it following this link http://blog.nowherelan.com/2011/12/28/adding-additional-ssl-ca-certificates/. It's my certificate which is expired.